# How does one discover their personal meaning?

Tags: meaning

The question stems from [this question](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/98855/two-ways-of-thinking-about-social-reality-progressive-fluid-vs-conservative-str). I attempted an answer, but the question I mentioned here was the obstruction from finishing.

In the conventional sense, as also put by the question, meaning is, archetypically, seen as derived relative to a value/belief system done by society and culture.

However, it is unclear to me, the **mechanism** which people derive meaning from in modern society. I understand that, there is an acknowledgement that meaning is a personal issue in modern society, but by what mechanism does one discover their personal meanings of different things in life?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some related discussions. Your question is a bit vague, so perhaps you could look at these and then ask something more focused.

What does meaning mean? [According to the major theories of concepts, where do meanings come from?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/77261/according-to-the-major-theories-of-concepts-where-do-meanings-come-from/77284#77284)

How personal can it be? [Isn't there an inherent contradiction in creating your own meaning in life?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/10064/isnt-there-an-inherent-contradiction-in-creating-your-own-meaning-in-life/72016#72016)

How philosophy can help us cultivate a practice of finding meaning in our own lives, by being a 'toolbox' to approach our challenges: [(Why) is this negative outlook on the concept of philosophy misguided?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/86865/why-is-this-negative-outlook-on-the-concept-of-philosophy-misguided/86866#86866)

Art and play as how we expand the scope of meaning: [Video games as new art](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/70048/video-games-as-new-art/77615#77615)

Comment: Those were good readings ( had gone through when you had posted answer itself) but it still feels inconclusive

Comment: @TrystwithFreedom: You might like this answer, on connecting to ideas & endeavours that go beyond our individuality & our lifespan, to find meaning: 'What are some philosophical works that explore constructing meaning in life from an agnostic or atheist view?' https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/91010/what-are-some-philosophical-works-that-explore-constructing-meaning-in-life-from/91017#91017